# is it possible to highlight gridview row which is recently updated in database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm new to vb.net.I'm developing a system where user will input values in given textboxes and system will display a gridview on button click. If the record already exist in database, it will update the date column to current date. So, what I want to know is, it possible to highlight the last updated row in gridview ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Sub barapp_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            If (e.Row.DataItem("Barcode") = TextBox1.Text) Then

                e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightPink


            End If

        End If

Comment: It's already working sir..